# Spring session redis as my session storage

Tags: spring-session

I am looking for an appropriate way to store the session attributes in third-party data storage like redis or mysql, how should I decide which one to pick? What scenario is fitful for using the redis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis would be better choice with expirations builtin